# How to get length of base64 string from base64decode?

Tags: cocos2d-x

`base64Decode()` is returning 0. It's not giving proper output. This is my code:

```
std::string source="iVBORw0KGgoAAA/j7..";
int len = 0;
unsigned char *buffer;
len = base64Decode((unsigned char*)source.c_str(), (unsigned int)source.length(), &buffer);
```

Comment: sir i did not understand what you say ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [why base64Decode is not return lenth of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409734/why-base64decode-is-not-return-lenth-of-string)

Answer (score 0):

**"\" is not included in Base64.**
Add a strict parameter thats check if your string contains characters outside the base64 range.
Post your result after :)